# Partially use upstream nameserver for a zone

Tags: dns

There's the following configuration.
Internal network - internal nameserver resolves example.com
Outside world - Amazon Route 53 resolves example.com

The internal network has special records for example.com, they are not able to move off these records to other domain (like example.internal), neither to use Route 53 nameservers internally.

Is it possible that for example
A www.example.com
goes to Route 53 nameserver
and all other records are handled by the original nameserver?

Copy the records statically to internal DNS is not a solution (only a temporary hack), as we use failover at Route 53 with a low TTL, so we'd lose this feature for the internal network.

What I know about the internal DNS is that it's Microsoft-based solution, coupled with ActiveDirectory.

Is there a solution for that?
Configuring something on the client side (SOCKS proxy under Chrome for example) is challenging, many clients inside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is a delegation. If you add:

```
www     NS  your.aws.dns.ip
```

That tells the client using that resolver to go to `your.aws.dns.ip` for the answer to `www.domain.com`.